# Unable to change language in Android default TextToSpeech

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I was trying to use:

```
_tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
_tts.setLanguage(new Locale("en"));
```

The result is always -2 (LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED), so I thought that I made a mistake in the string given to the constructor.

Then I tried using (Obviously English is supported, no?)

```
 _tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
```

But to no avail and with the same result.

Why can't I change the language of the TTS engine?

My device's Android is version 2.3, TTS engine is PICO.

```
public void onInit(final int status) { 
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) { 
      _init = true; Log.d(TAG, "TTS init completed succesfully.");        
      setQueueMode(TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to set the language before initializing the **TTS** engine, instead of setting the language after creating the object do it at `onInit` callback.

```
public void onInit(final int status) { 
  if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) { 
    _init = true;
     Log.d(TAG, "TTS init completed succesfully.");  
     int result = _tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);         

  } 
}
```